# Pandas: How to convert integer born date to age

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a df, you can have it by running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dfs = """
BornDate
2   19850100
3   19000100
5   19850100
6   19000100
7   19820100
8   19850100
9   19000100
10  19790100
11  19850100

"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfs.strip()), sep='\s+', 
                  dtype={"BornDate": int})
df
```

The output is:

```
BornDate
2   19850100
3   19000100
5   19850100
6   19000100
7   19820100
8   19850100
9   19000100
10  19790100
11  19850100
```

What I need is converting the `BornDate` to age base on a variable **ValuationDate**,
the age equals `ValuationDate` minus `BornDate`:

```
ValuationDate = 20201231
ValuationDate=pd.to_datetime(ValuationDate)
df['BornDate']=pd.to_datetime(df['BornDate'])

df['BornDate']=ValuationDate-df['BornDate']

df['BornDate']
```

But it returns:

```
2    00:00:00.000351
3    00:00:00.001201
5    00:00:00.000351
6    00:00:00.001201
7    00:00:00.000381
8    00:00:00.000351
9    00:00:00.001201
10   00:00:00.000411
11   00:00:00.000351
Name: BornDate, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The output should be:

```
2    35.1
3    12.01
5    35.1
6    120.1
7    38.1
8    35.1
9    120.1
10   41.1
11   35.1
```

Comment: Why are there no days in your sample data - i.e., why are the days zero and not greater than or equal to 1? `19850100`

Comment: For records 3 and 6/9 I don't understand why they are different: 12.01 or 120.1?

Comment: @Corralien sorry that is a mistake. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your column `BornDate` is in format the same as `ValuationDate` in `YYYYmmdd`, then, you should change your codes as follows to cater for this date string format:

```
ValuationDate = 20201231
ValuationDate=pd.to_datetime(ValuationDate, format='%Y%m%d')
df['BornDate']=pd.to_datetime(df['BornDate'], format='%Y%m%d')

df['BornDate'] = (ValuationDate - df['BornDate']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

**Data Input**

Modified the day of each date from invalid `00` to `01`:

```
    BornDate
2   19850101
3   19000101
5   19850101
6   19000101
7   19820101
8   19850101
9   19000101
10  19790101
11  19850101
```

**Output**

```
      BornDate
2    35.998001
3   120.999062
5    35.998001
6   120.999062
7    38.998747
8    35.998001
9   120.999062
10   41.999493
11   35.998001
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dt.microseconds`:

```
>>> df['BornDate'].dt.microseconds.div(10)
2      35.1
3     120.1
5      35.1
6     120.1
7      38.1
8      35.1
9     120.1
10     41.1
11     35.1
Name: BornDate, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @William. I don't understand your choice to accept the other answer?